# Merge [public-pensions] and [private-pensions] into [pensions]

Tags: discussion, tags

Both existing tags have few questions associated with them yet there is no tag for pensions in general. Given that it is difficult to distinguish between the two in some countries* it might be better to just have one tag: [pensions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pensions).

*From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pension_fund#Public_vs._private_pension_funds):

> In certain countries the distinction between public or government pension funds and private pension funds may be difficult to assess. In others, the distinction is made sharply in law, with very specific requirements for administration and investment.